# MBProgressHUD not updating progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I am importing multiple photos from photos library and I want to show the progress using `MBProgressHUD`. I am using `QBImagePickerController` to import photos. My photos are imported successfully. However the progress bar in `MBProgressHUD` is not updating. The following is my code

```
-(void)qb_imagePickerController:(QBImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didSelectAssets:(NSArray *)assets {
   if (imagePickerController.filterType == QBImagePickerControllerFilterTypePhotos) {
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];]

    // Set the determinate mode to show task progress.
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
    hud.delegate = self;

    hud.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Importing Photos", nil);
    hud.dimBackground = YES;
    hud.detailsLabelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    hud.detailsLabelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait...", nil);
    hud.progress = 0.0f;

    [self importPhotosForArray:assets];
   }
    [self dismissImagePickerController];
}

 - (void) importPhotosForArray:(NSArray *)info {
       for (ALAsset *selectedImageAsset in info) {
       ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetsLibrary assetForURL:[selectedImageAsset defaultRepresentation].url resultBlock: ^(ALAsset *asset){
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];
        if (imageRef) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

            // Create a file name for the image
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo-%@.png", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
            // Now we get the full path to the file
            NSString *fullPathToFile = [self.folder.fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
            // Write out the data.
            [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

            sleep(1.0);
            progress = ++index/[info count];

            [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;

            if (progress >= 1.0) {
                [[MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view] hide:YES];
                    [self reloadData];
            }
        }
    } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error){
        // Handle failure.
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];
   }
}
```

Comment: Does the `MBProgressHUD` successfully hide upon completion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code. Replace your `importPhotosForArray` method with the following.

```
- (void) importPhotosForArray:(NSArray *)info {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{
    __block float progress = 0.0f;
    __block float index = 0.0f;

    for (ALAsset *selectedImageAsset in info) {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [selectedImageAsset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];
        if (imageRef) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

            // Create a file name for the image
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo-%@.png", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
            // Now we get the full path to the file
            NSString *fullPathToFile = [self.folder.fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
            // Write out the data.
            [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

            sleep(1);

            progress = ++index/[info count];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // Instead we could have also passed a reference to the HUD
                // to the HUD to myProgressTask as a method parameter.
                [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;
            });

            if (progress >= 1.0) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Instead we could have also passed a reference to the HUD
                    // to the HUD to myProgressTask as a method parameter.
                    [[MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view] hide:YES];
                    [self reloadData];
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: @kathrineshineshine see my answer to understand **why** this [code-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) works. It's important to spend a few minutes learning about this so that you don't ask a duplicate question (and waste your own time) about a different UI element in a month.

Answer (score 0):

declare  MBProgressHUD As property and use it every where.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MBProgressHUD *hud;

-(void)qb_imagePickerController:(QBImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didSelectAssets:(NSArray *)assets {

    if (imagePickerController.filterType == QBImagePickerControllerFilterTypePhotos) {

            self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];]

           // Set the determinate mode to show task progress.
           self.hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminateHorizontalBar;
           self.hud.delegate = self;

           self.hud.labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Importing Photos", nil);
           self.hud.dimBackground = YES;
           self.hud.detailsLabelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
           self.hud.detailsLabelText = NSLocalizedString(@"Please wait...", nil);
           self.hud.progress = 0.0f;

           [self importPhotosForArray:assets];
        }
            [self dismissImagePickerController];
}

- (void) importPhotosForArray:(NSArray *)info {

   for (ALAsset *selectedImageAsset in info) {

          ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

          [assetsLibrary assetForURL:[selectedImageAsset defaultRepresentation].url resultBlock: ^(ALAsset *asset){

          ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
          CGImageRef imageRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];

        if (imageRef) {

              UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
              NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

        // Create a file name for the image
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo-%@.png", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
        // Now we get the full path to the file
        NSString *fullPathToFile = [self.folder.fullPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        // Write out the data.
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:NO];

        sleep(1.0);
        progress = ++index/[info count];

        self.hud.progress = progress;

        if (progress >= 1.0) {

         [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];

                [self reloadData];
        }
    }
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error){
    // Handle failure.
    NSLog(@"Failure");
  }];
}
}
```

Try this
Because as per your code when u update progress every time new object of MBProgressHUD get and update

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have done that already but no success

Answer (score 0):

UI updates (i.e. changes to the progress bar) [must be made on the **main** thread](https://chritto.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/updating-the-ui-from-another-thread/) or you may suffer from unpredictable side effects.

> The user interface element may not be redrawn after your property changes

I believe that `ALAssetsLibrary.assetForURL` is automatically happening in a background thread. To get around that you want to use a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7233077/1241782) that lets you run the UI updates on the main thread. In this case your UI updates would be this line

```
[MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;
```

so try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.navigationController.view].progress = progress;
});
```

Also, you should verify that `++index/[info count]` is actually increasing as you expect it to by printing the value out each time `index` updates.